# Convert date retrieved from SQL server to string in MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

Hi I have a windows form application. its has a database table with two columns of DATE type. I can insert the dates in the columns easily, in MM/dd/yyyy format. But when it comes to retrieving data from the table, I use the following code.

> SqlDataAdapter sda=new SqlDataAdapter("select * from table",conn);
>   DataSet ds=new DataSet(); sda.Fill(ds,"table");

Now i need to display the content of ds which contains DATE in a label. If I do this:

> label1.Text=ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
>   It displays complete date with 12:00:00 AM time as well! I want to format this value as MM/dd/yyyy. I am using c#. Please help.

Basically I want to know How can i format a string into DATE format like "MM/dd/yyyy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-

```
 string date1= date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ToString` with a custom date format string.

```
label1.Text = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                          .First().Field<DateTime>(0).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

(note that you need to add also `using System.Linq` for the code above)

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)